# Cookie set on the response doesn't show up in subsequent request to server until browser has made two new subsequent requests

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

An initial request is made to the server, and in the response a cookie is added:

```
response.addCookie(studyPrefsCookie);
```

On the web page, in the developer tools, I can see the cookie that was just set. Great. Here's a pic:

[image]

My assumption is that now that the cookie is set, every subsequent request to my web application (same domain, same servletcontext, etc), will now contain this cookie value in the cookies available from the request object. However, it appears that on the very next request, the cookie value is not there, even though by inspecting the request in the developer tools shows the cookie value as being sent. On the second subsequent request, it shows up normally. Here's what the request looks like, same each time from the browser:

[image]

I even tested this again by starting from scratch, and then making an ajax call after the the first page load, back to the server. First ajax call had all the right cookies as far as the browser was concerned, but the httpservletrequest object's cookies didn't have it. Making another identical ajax call, now the server found the cookie value. Is this expected behavior?

I'm reading the cookie the same way on the server side, with some helper methods:

```
Cookie[] cookies = studyCookieService.getCookiesByName(request.getCookies(), "STUDYPREFS");
if(cookies.length > 0 && studyCookieService.doesCookieContainValue(cookies[0], studyCookieService.getConsentNotCompletedCookieValueWithoutStudyId())){
        //redirect
        return "redirect:/" + STUDY_CONTROLLER_REQUEST_PATH;
```

--service methods

```
public Cookie[] getCookiesByName(Cookie[] cookies, String cookieName){
    List<Cookie> matchingCookies = new ArrayList<Cookie>();

    if (cookies != null) {
      for (Cookie ck : cookies) {
        if (cookieName.equals(ck.getName())) {
          matchingCookies.add(ck);
        }
      }
    }

    return matchingCookies.toArray(new Cookie[matchingCookies.size()]); 
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the Cookie you set and  how you retrieve it?

Comment: i added some more details